# Resolve all promises in an array of json - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I need to resolve all promises in an array of json, like this:

```
let list = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Cat')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Dog')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 3,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Mouse')
        })
    }
]
```

I use **bluebird** promises.
I used a for cycle to iterate all items, I would know if there was some way more elegant.

**Expected result:**

```
[ { data: 'Cat', id: 1 },
  { data: 'Dog', id: 2 },
  { data: 'Mouse', id: 3 } ]
```

Comment: `Promise.all(list.map(x => x.data))`? Not sure what you mean by "resolve all promises in an array".

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the actual input? (What you've shown is not JSON as claimed, and there doesn't seem to be a reason to use promises at all here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, Promise.all and array.map like the others, but the result is correct

```js
let list = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Cat')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Dog')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 3,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Mouse')
        })
    }
]    

Promise.all(list.map(item => item.data.then(data => ({...item, data}))))
// that's it, that's what you want, the rest is for show now
.then(results => {
   console.log(results);
});
```

though, that's **Native** Promises ... you may want to look into [Promise.props](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) and/or [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) in bluebird for possibly simpler code yet

It could well be as simple as

```
Promise.map(list, Promise.props)
.then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

> tested the above, and yes, it is that simple - the snippet below has **my own** version of `Promise.map` and `Promise.props` - and works (at least in this case) identically to bluebird

```js
Promise.props = obj => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return Promise.all(Object.values(obj)).then(results => Object.assign({}, ...results.map((result, index) => ({[keys[index]]: result}))));
};

Promise.map = (array, fn, thisArg) => Promise.all(Array.from(array, (...args) => fn.apply(thisArg, args)));

let list = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Cat')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Dog')
        })
    },
    { 
        id: 3,
        data: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('Mouse')
        })
    }
]    

Promise.map(list, Promise.props)
.then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: `{...item, data}` is nice

Comment: to be fair on bluebird though, `Promise.map(list, Promise.props)` (in the hidden snippet) is kinda sweet too (having written my own versions of `Promise.map` and `Promise.probs` I finally found a use for them :p )

Answer (score 2):

Resolve Promise.all() to an actual usable array of JSON.

The problem: Promise.all() resolves to an array of resolved promises. To see why this is an issue, copy and paste this into your console:

```
var promise1 = fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/2'); // C-3PO
var promise2 = fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/3'); // R2-D2

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
    .then(res => console.log(res)); // resolved promises - trash...
```

See how there's no actual usable data in those resolved promises..? On the web, you need to call another promise to convert them to text or html or, most likely, beloved json. But how can you do this efficiently?

Well, then solution to our Promise.all() issue is... more Promise.all()!!!

Example:

```
var promise3 = fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1'); // Luke
var promise4 = fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/4'); // Luke's daddy

Promise.all([promise3, promise4])
    .then(res => Promise.all([res[0].json(), res[1].json()]))
    .then(res => console.log(res)); // real data :)
```

Hope this helps someone! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) & some JavaScript.

```
let list = [];
let promise = Promise.all(list.map(entry => entry.data));
promise.then((results) => {
  let final = results.map((result, index) => {
    return {data: result, id: list[index].id};
  });
  console.log(final);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) may be a good fit here:

```js
Promise.all(list.map(entry => entry.data)).then((resolved) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: It resolves the promises but I will have an array of resolved values as result. What I mean is, with your solution I have: list = [Dog, Cat, Mouse]. I want list=[{id:1, data: Dog}, ... e so on... of course I could generate the array I need but I'm searching a more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

You just need create an array of promises. you can do it with `for` or `map`

```
let promises = []

for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++)
  promises.push(list.data)

Promise.all(promises).then(resultList => { ... }).catch(err => { ... })
```

or simplest may with `map`

```
Promise.all(list.map(p => p.data)).then(resultList => { ... }).catch(err => { ... })
```

Comment: It resolves the promises but I will have an array of resolved values as result. What I mean is, with your solution I have: list = [Dog, Cat, Mouse]. I want list=[{id:1, data: Dog}, ... e so on... of course I could generate the array I need but I'm searching a more elegant way

Comment: @tinytanks I got it. and you should add then on your promise calling somthing like below: 

`Promise.all(list.map(p => p.data.then(data => {...p, data}))).then(resultList => { ... }).catch(err => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash lib to minimize your code

```
const _ = require('lodash');

Promise.all(_.map(list, 'data')).then((data)=>{
    list.map((item,ind)=>{item.data = data[ind]});
    console.log(list);
})
```

Comment: It resolves the promises but I will have an array of resolved values as result. What I mean is, with your solution I have: list = [Dog, Cat, Mouse]. I want list=[{id:1, data: Dog}, ... e so on... of course I could generate the array I need but I'm searching a more elegant way

Comment: so, load a 20k library to save 8 characters of code?

Comment: @Jaromanda less code implies less error and clean code hence more elegant, if you have big project than you should use these lib to eliminate unwanted trivial code.

Comment: sure, `Promise.map(list, Promise.props)` is the same length as the shortest version of your code `Promise.all(_.map(list, 'data'))` ... but doesn't require another library ... less code **or less library** = win win

Comment: i agree with you :)